# Postgresql Oledb column name quoting

Tags: postgresql, oledb

I have:

```
INSERT INTO XYZ (c1, c2, range) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

OleDb call fails here because of `range` is a reserved keyword - how to quote it through the OleDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use double quotes ":

```
INSERT INTO XYZ (c1, c2, "range") VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```